# How to go to the bottom cells on google sheets on open for all Tabs

Tags: google-sheets

I created the following script to run in Google sheets on open to be able to automatically go to the bottom row of the sheet.
enter code here

```
function onOpen() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var mysheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

var lastrow = mysheet.getLastRow();

mysheet.setActiveCell(mysheet.getDataRange().offset(lastrow-1, 0, 1,         1));  
};
```

This script does work for the active tab but not the additional tabs?

Answer (score 1):

Find the number of sheets in the spreadsheet then loop through each sheet.

```
function onOpen() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var numSht = ss.getNumSheets() //get the number of sheets in spreadsheet
for(var i=0;i<numSht;i++){ //loop through the sheets
var mySheet=ss.getSheets()[i]
var lastrow =mySheet.getLastRow()
Utilities.sleep(2000)//may not be needed
var sel =mySheet.setActiveCell(mySheet.getDataRange().offset(lastrow-1, 0,  1, 1));
}
}
```